# Bootstrap column ignoring content padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We're using a minimal version of bootstrap on our site, and I've got a problem with using our button styles. The bootstrap columns are ignoring the padding/border on the buttons. I tried using full bootstrap (and their buttons), and it seemed to work. Does anyone know what I need to add to the `btn` style to make bootstrap include it's padding/borders?

[Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/7hxa7/) to a jsfiddle with our bootstrap and css file linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized, our button class was missing `display:inline-block;`, that fixed it.